# Empty Dataframe when scraping specific column from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to try to scrape some specific columns (Company details column) in the CNBC Nasdaq 100 website specifically the Adobe stocks, below is the snippet of my code

```
# Importing Libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd

def get_company_info(url):
    original_url = url
    key = {}
    l = []

    page_response = requests.get(url, timeout=240)
    page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")

    name = page_content.find('div',{"class":"quote-section-header large-header"}).find("span",{"class":"symbol"}).text
    description = page_content.find_all('div',{"class":"moduleBox"})

    for items in description:
        for i in range(len(items.find_all("tr"))-1):
            # Gather data
            key["stock_desc"] = items.find_all("td", {"class":"desc"})[i].find('div',attrs={'id':'descLong'}).text
            shares = items.find_all("td").find("table",attrs={"id":"shares"})
            for rest_of_items in shares:
                for i in range(len(items.find_all("tr"))-1):
                    key["stock_outstanding-shares"] = items.find_all("td", {"class":"bold aRit"})[i].text
                    key["stock_ownership"] = items.find_all("td", {"class":"bold aRit"})[i].text
                    key["stock_market_cap"] = items.find_all("td", {"class":"bold aRit"})[i].text
                    key["stock_lastSplit"] = items.find_all("td", {"class":"bold aRit"})[i].text
                    # Print ("")
                    l.append(key)         

    key['name'] = name
    df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    print(df)

    return key, df

get_company_info("https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/?symbol=ADBE&tab=profile")
```

So, I'm keen to get the result in dataframe so that I can change to CSV file, but my code keep showing empty dataframe result, Below are the error shown
[image: Error empty dataframe]

The result I wanted is something like this
[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you are looking for is not available in the url you requested. This is because the information is fetched by the page using a JavaScript. Which in turn requests a different URL which provides the data.

Example code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page=requests.get("https://apps.cnbc.com/view.asp?symbol=ADBE.O&uid=stocks/summary")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

Name=soup.find("h5",id="companyName").text
stock_desc= soup.find("div",id="descLong").text

table=soup.find("table",id="shares")
details=table.find_all("td", class_="bold aRit")
stock_outstanding_shares= details[0].text
stock_ownership= details[1].text
stock_market_cap= details[2].text
stock_lastSplit= details[3].text
```

You can create dataframe and export to csv.